# How to create Array in C++ based on the input for number of strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am stuck with a task where, I have to input the number of strings to be processed and then display the even positioned characters and odd positioned characters, separately.

I am confused about how to declare the string array after I enter the input for the number of strings.

Can I call a pointer to a two-dimensional array and use the int value of number of strings to be processed? If yes, how? If no, what is the alternative?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> sArray(number_of_strings)`.

Comment: dont use raw pointers when you don't need them. You need raw pointers when you want to point to some other object, but first you need that other object. Messing around with pointers for arrays in C++ was ok in the last century but not anymore ;)

Comment: please add your efforts = code you wrote.

Comment: So it seems you are learning how to program in a C style even though you think you are learning C++. In C, you would write `char** arr = malloc(number*sizeof(char*));` and similar code will work in C++ `char** arr = (char**)malloc(number*sizeof(char*));`. But really you should be learning the C++ way of doing things which is to use `std::vector` and `std::string`, much less confusing.

Comment: I highly appreciate you guys for your feedback. In fact, I am a C programmer and have been out of practice for over a decade. I just want to get back into coding and learn new languages and techniques. I will try the std::vector and std::string. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I call a pointer to a two-dimensional array and use the int value of number of strings to be processed? If yes, how? If no, what is the alternative?

Yes, you can allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()` wherein inside the `()` when you specify its size, you have to include that integer (number of strings) multiplied by the size of how-many-bytes your string would take. (which is the number of characters + 1 for the null character)

However its definitely better to discard this approach and as mentioned, use an `std::vector` of `std::string`s instead. For what you asked:

> I am confused about how to declare the string array after I enter the input for the number of strings.

Declare a vector of strings, fill it with strings uptil your input number (signifying the no. of strings) running inside a loop and then use as you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{ 
  int n; // number of strings 
  std::cin>>n;
  std::vector<std::string> stringvector;
  std::string s;
  for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
  {  
      std::cin>>s; stringvector.push_back(s);
  }
  // for(auto i:stringvector) std::cout<<i;
}
```

This should get you started :)

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I suppose I was following the old track. But now, I am getting an idea about what I was missing.